# How to make all tabs in QTabBar not been selected?

Tags: qt, qtabbar

How to make all tabs in QTabBar not been selected?

Thank you.

Comment: What will you show to the user if no tab is selected?

Comment: I use QTabBar as a tool to save bookmarks. So I show user some views (QTreeView and QTableView) he can surf the datamodel by. When user wants to save the current context, he makes a tab. So if no tab is selected i'll show the same views with other context set up.

Comment: There is no way of deselecting tabs. Just create a new tab appropriately named to show that it is default context.

Comment: Thanks, i've already done it this way. But the specification insists the way i described above. So, peharps, will write my own control.

Answer (score 2):

@ilyabvt at forum.crossplatform.ru suggested to create first fake tab and use Qt Style Sheets to make it's width = 0:

```
QTabBar::tab:first {
  max-width: 0px;
}
```

This approach works fine with QTabBar integrated in QTabWidget. But unfortunately doesn't work with single QTabBar (look the screenshot below). Maybe it is my fault, but i cant find out where the mistake.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's supposed to be like radio buttons, i.e. there is always one selected. If none of the tabs are active perhaps the whole bar should be disabled.